# Playing MIDI files in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, playback, midi

How can I play MIDI files with VB.NET? I tried using WAV, but they are too big. Any help?

Comment: That always sounds like a good idea.  Until you hear what it sounds like.

Answer (score 1):

look at this article i used it before and it works.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8506/Simple-VB-NET-MIDI-Wave-Play-Class

just copy paste that code in your project.
create variable which holds your midi and
call the play method.

you can also try this.(not sure about it.)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141756

Answer (score 1):

Using MIDI files can be a good idea in regard to size, but IMO a horrible idea when it comes to actual sound (or lack there-of :) ). You can find users which do music too, and has a little better alternative set up or connected to their system, but to make users fire up their MIDI instruments and so forth to listen to a MIDI-track in a software can be a bad idea if unexpected.

Most users though are stuck with the built in wave synth from Microsoft which is a torture instrument (pun intended) and should probably not be used ;)

Why not consider compressing your wave data instead using MP3 or some other excellent compressor such as AAC, Ogg Vorbis ?

This will reduce the original data amount to at least 1/10 of the original size and unless you are providing a whole album, should be overcome-able.

You can find various ways to do this, from [simple such as this one](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/119460/playing-mp3-file-with-vb.net) using the Media Player, or more [low-level such as this one](http://whenimbored.xfx.net/2011/01/an-mp3-decoder-written-in-vb/) which decodes the MP3 file.

Also take a look at [SlimDX](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/).